# Make Case When in select sum query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_CODE),  ZERO_DAYS_FLAG FROM (
SELECT  SUM (CLASS_BELOW_BALANCE) AS ZERO_DAYS_FLAG, ACCOUNT_CODE
FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCES 
WHERE MERCHANT_STATUS != 'Suspended'
AND MERCHANT_CSP_CODE IN ('1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '6' , '7')
AND CHECK_BALANCE_DATE BETWEEN '01-SEP-15' AND '30-SEP-15' 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_CODE) GROUP BY ZERO_DAYS_FLAG ORDER BY ZERO_DAYS_FLAG;
```

and the result in:

```
COUNT(DISTINCTACCOUNT_CODE) ZERO_DAYS_FLAG         
--------------------------- ---------------------- 
2026                        0                      
2036                        1                      
2005                        2                      
1874                        3                      
2020                        4                      
2074                        5                      
2224                        6                      
2343                        7                      
2460                        8                      
2666                        9                      
2606                        10                     
2511                        11                     
2571                        12
```

What i need is adding a case when the ZERO_DAYS_FLAG is greater than 6 then the result to be summed as 6 days like this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCTACCOUNT_CODE) ZERO_DAYS_FLAG         
--------------------------- ---------------------- 
2026                        0                      
2036                        1                      
2005                        2                      
1874                        3                      
2020                        4                      
2074                        5                      
2224                        6+
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the result you want.  Do you really want to remove the last 6 rows from the initial query?  Or would you want 13 rows returned with the `zero_days_flag` all set to 6+?  Or would you want to add together the counts of the last 7 rows and roll that up to a "6+" bucket?

Comment: Yes I need the first 5 results to be displayed as is and to add together the counts of the last 7 rows and roll that up to a "6+"

Comment: OK.  So in your desired output, the first column shouldn't be 2224, right?  It should be 2224+2343+2460+2666+2606+2511+2571?

Comment: yes it is exactly the required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN ZERO_DAYS_FLAG > 5 THEN '+6' ELSE CAST(ZERO_DAYS_FLAG AS CHAR) END
```

Like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_CODE),
  CASE WHEN ZERO_DAYS_FLAG > 5 THEN '6+' ELSE CAST(ZERO_DAYS_FLAG AS CHAR) END ZERO_DAYS_FLAG
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(CLASS_BELOW_BALANCE) AS ZERO_DAYS_FLAG, ACCOUNT_CODE
  FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCES 
  WHERE MERCHANT_STATUS != 'Suspended'
  AND MERCHANT_CSP_CODE IN ('1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '6' , '7')
  AND CHECK_BALANCE_DATE BETWEEN '01-SEP-15' AND '30-SEP-15' 
  GROUP BY ACCOUNT_CODE) X
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ZERO_DAYS_FLAG > 5 THEN '6+' ELSE CAST(ZERO_DAYS_FLAG AS CHAR) END
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ZERO_DAYS_FLAG > 5 THEN '6+' ELSE CAST(ZERO_DAYS_FLAG AS CHAR) END;
```

Note: The value "6+" in the original query has been changed to "+6" to allow it to still be recognised as an integer in case the result is also being used by an application. All credit to OP for this idea.

Comment: I got this result: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 63

Comment: I got this error : ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

Comment: Can you please post a link to an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your schema and a few rows of data (especially the ones that are causing the "invalid number" error)?

Comment: I suspect that error is coming from your application layer - if so, you need to change from `row.getInt("ZERO_DAYS_FLAG")` to  `row.getString("ZERO_DAYS_FLAG")` because the datatype of that column is now text (to accommodate that "+" in "6+") whereas before it was integer (btw, that's java code, but use the equivalent in C# or whatever you're using)

Comment: The problem is that one result of the case is a string and another is a number.  That's why I concatenated an empty string in my answer.

Comment: I modified the '6+' to by '+6' and it worked fine. Thank you so much. please modify the query so that everyone can use.

Comment: @AhmedSelim Thanks for the feed back. That was very clever of you to solve the failure to parse as an integer by changing "6+" to "+6". I will remember that trick :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_CODE),  
    CASE WHEN ZERO_DAYS_FLAG > 6 THEN '6+' ELSE ZERO_DAYS_FLAG || '' END AS zero_days_flag 
FROM (
     SELECT  
         SUM (CLASS_BELOW_BALANCE) AS ZERO_DAYS_FLAG, ACCOUNT_CODE
     FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCES 
     WHERE MERCHANT_STATUS != 'Suspended'
     AND MERCHANT_CSP_CODE IN ('1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' , '6' , '7')
     AND CHECK_BALANCE_DATE BETWEEN '01-SEP-15' AND '30-SEP-15' 
     GROUP BY ACCOUNT_CODE) 
  GROUP BY ZERO_DAYS_FLAG ORDER BY ZERO_DAYS_FLAG;
```

Comment: here is the result: 2026 0
2036 1
2005 2
1874 3
2020 4
2074 5
2224 6
2511 6+
2247 6+
2606 6+
2462 6+
2404 6+
2460 6+